# Independence of random variable and random vector implies conditional independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

I have this interesting problem from probability theory stating as follows:

> Let $ X, Y, Z $ be three random variables such that $ Z $ and the vector $ (X,Y) $ are independent. We are to prove that given $ Y $, $ X $ and $ Z $ are independent.

I cannot really solve it due to lack of intuition, and I do not know how to solve this as it was not stated whether or not the variables are discrete or continuous and which is which. I thank everyone who can help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aim is to show that
$$
\mathrm{E}[f(X)g(Z)\mid Y]=\mathrm{E}[f(X)\mid Y]\mathrm{E}[g(Z)\mid Y]\tag{1}
$$
holds for all, say, measurable and bounded $f$, $g$ under the assumption that
$$
\mathrm{E}[u(X,Y)v(Z)]=\mathrm{E}[u(X,Y)]\mathrm{E}[v(Z)]\tag{2}
$$
holds for all, say, measurable and bounded $u$, $v$.

To show $(1)$ we note that the RHS is integrable and $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. Note also that under the independence assumption, we have that $\mathrm{E}[g(Z)\mid Y]=\mathrm{E}[g(Z)]$. Thus, we only need to prove that
$$
\mathrm{E}\big[\mathrm{E}[f(X)\mid Y]\mathrm{E}[g(Z)]\mathbf{1}_{Y\in B}\big]=\mathrm{E}[f(X)g(Z)\mathbf{1}_{Y\in B}],\quad B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
This should be fairly obvious using $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f_{x,z|y}=f_{x,z,y}/f_y=f_{x,y}f_z/f_y=f_{x|y}f_z=f_{x|y}f_{z|y},
$$
where the first and third equalities hold by bayes theorem, and the second and fourth equality by the independence assumption.